# Is "koramiko" gender neutral or always male?

Tags: word-meaning, word-formation, gender

*amik·o*, like most other nouns in Esperanto (and other than most or all Esperanto terms for specific relatives), is, as far as I know, sex- / gender-neutral.

Is that also the case for *kor·amik·o*? Or does *koramiko* always mean "boyfriend" and never "girlfriend or boyfriend"?

If the latter, does Esperanto (be it traditionally, or considering proposed reforms like parentismo) have a sex- / gender-neutral word for "girlfriend or boyfriend"?

---

Laŭ mia scio *amik·o* estas, kiel la plejmulto de Esperantaj o-vortoj (kaj alie ol la plejmultaj aŭ eĉ ĉiuj Esperantaj esprimoj por specifaj parencoj), seks-neŭtrala.

Ĉu same ankaŭ *kor·amik·o*? Aŭ ĉu *koramiko* ĉiam signifas "vira koramiko" kaj neniam "koramikino aŭ vira aŭ neduumula koramiko"?

Se ĝi havas nur la viran signifon, ĉu ekzistas Esperanta vorto (aŭ tradicia, aŭ pere de proponita reformo kiel parentismo) por la rilata seks-neŭtrala signifo?

Comment: Just to throw extra confusion into the question, according to PIV not even _amiko_ is neutral: “viro, kiu estas ligita kun alia homo per reciproka inklino”

Comment: Eble ĉi tio estas afero  kiu estas ne tute fiksita kaj ni, kiel parolantoj, ankoraŭ povas subtile influi la lingvon? (mi nur esperas ke la lingvo iras en la direkto de plia simetrio, ne al plia konfuzo)

Answer (score 4):

In essence your question is about when a gender marker is needed and when it is just superfluous. Since Esperanto has only one gender marker, the female *-in*, this boils down to it.

I see this question more like a scale of tones than a strict on/off matter. While there still are people who use the female marker *-in* in titles like *instruistino, pentristino, verkistino*, they are in a clear minority. The closer to your immediate circle of relatives and friends you get, the more likely you make a distinction. Let me illustrate. Many already use *amiko* in a gender-neutral way (but not all as Neil Roberts points out in *sia komento*), but how many use *kuzo* that way? How about one's parents and siblings? Here I bet that very few use other than the gender-specific *patro, patrino* resp. *frato, fratino*. At least I count *koramiko, koramikino* into this innermost circle, since those words exist to denote that relationship in the first place.

When it comes to your other question, whether there is a gender-neutral term for that "special one", I doubt there is any official one, but you have to come up with a suitable one for that situation. Here are some possibilities (credits to Neil Roberts for some examples).

In a two-men or two-women relationship the persons are likely to define the other in terms of *edzo, koramiko* resp. *edzino, koramikino*.

There is the *laŭfundamenta* use of the prefix *ge-*:

- *Marta kaj Johano estas gekoramikoj.*
- *Invitu viajn gekoramikojn al nia festo.*

However in the latter example at least to me it is not so clear how many boy/girlfriends you have.

There is also *nekutima* use of the prefix *ge-*:

- *Per amrendevua retejo oni povas trovi gekoramikon.*

Some use this singular *ge-* to mark gender-neutrality despite what [PMEG says about such use](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/prefiksoj/ge.html#i-v8z).

Whatever term you end up using, be prepared to explain it(*).

*: I worked as a volunteer during *la 104-a UK* and found that you need to explain a lot of things, things that are clear to you, but not for esperantists from other countries and continents.

Comment: Re: “I think there is seldom need for [a gender neutral term]”, I think the need to know whether this is neutral or not would be quite common in the plural. For example “Marta kaj Johano estas [ge]koramikoj” or “invitu viajn [ge]koramikojn al nia festo”. Even in the singular it is important when the person is hypothetical: “per amrendevua retejo oni povas trovi koramik[in]on”.

Comment: Mi ne konis la malrekomendon de PMEG pri *ge-* ... Interese. Dankon.

Comment: Only one gender marker? What about [_vir-_](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/afiksecaj_elementoj/radikoj_kunmetajhoj.html#i-asp) (and the [unofficial _-iĉ-_](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/icx.html#icx.0&))?

Comment: PMEG ne malrekomendas tian uzadon de ge-, relegu bone la sekcion. Ĝi nur malrekomendas uzi ge- tiel ĉe vortoj, kiuj estas klare seksneŭtralaj, ekzemple "gehomo" kaj "geinfano".

Comment: @RobinvanderVliet While the **"Ĉiuokaze tia uzo de GE estas tute nebezonata ĉe radikoj, kiuj estas sendube sekse neŭtralaj"** part  in PMEG indeed might not apply, because "**sendube** sekse neŭtrala" doesn't seem to be the case for _amiko_, and even less so for _koramiko_, maybe Juha refers not just to that, but also to **"Pro ĉi tiuj kialoj oni povas kritiki tian unu-nombran uzon de GE kiel reforman aŭ eĉ kontraŭ-Fundamentan."**. Laŭ mi "... despite what PMEG says" ne necese signifas, ke PMEG malrekomendas tian uzadon. Ĝi povas signifi, ke PMEG ja mencias, ke tia uzado ja kritikeblas.

Comment: Originally a word like _amiko_ denoted only a male friend and as Neil pointed out, there are people who still think that way, although quite possibly the majority thinks otherwise today. _Vir-_ as a prefix for humans is definitely not from the time of Zamenhof, but is much recent use. So I see it as a modern proposition for a solution (albeit better than _-iĉ_).

Comment: When it comes to PMEG, my reading of it is that Wennergren is against of singular _ge-_ for the reasons _ri_ lists up. In any case all proposed solutions set on a scale from _La Fundamento_ up to total reformists (possibly with a need to rewrite the past works). Most Esperantists find a point somewhere between the extreme ends, what they can and cannot accept as a change. Where that point is varies from person to person.

Answer (score 1):

No, *amiko* can be officially female too. But *culturally* it is not as gender neutral as English, with its additional and over-strong *girlfriend* and *boyfriend*. Explicit usage would be *amikino* and *viramiko*.

There are cultural uses where gender neutrality still is not established, like in family relations (*onklo, onklino*).

It is a matter of what you want to explain. Hence *kuracisto* may actually be female; even in more gender specific languages, like German: *Hausarzt* vs. *Hausärztin*, where it is almost lying, but economical usage. For instance while explaining one was to the doctor.

Do ne timu uzi la terminon *koramiko* en nespecifa signifo.

Comment: Sed ne temas pri `amiko` sed pri `koramiko`. Ial, en normala uzo ĝi estas aparte kaj neregule vira. Estas bona ideo tamen kuraĝigi novajn parolantojn uzi tion neŭtre.

Comment: Nun la respondo havas -1 poentojn; mi volas rimarkigi ke temas pri -2+1, do ne nur unu kontraŭa opinio.

Comment: Mi povas kompreni la frustron ne havi perfektan, simetrian, koheran lingvon. Bedaŭrinde, kiam io tia estas fingremontrita, kelkaj preferas puni la portinton de la mesaĝo, anstataŭ klopodi korekti la problemon per aliaj rimedoj. Tial mi ŝatas vian respondon (rekoni la nunan situacion kaj kuraĝigi la seksneŭtran uzon) same kiel la [klaran, seksneŭtran kaj normigklopodan difinon de Revo.](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/amik.html).

Answer (score 0):

Mallonga respondo:

`koramiko` estas **praktike** viro en normala lingvouzo ([Duolingo](https://en.duolingo.com/dictionary/Esperanto/koramiko/8d2ce2e0b287b89bab975c350d057252),[Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koramiko)). Tio estas fakto lingva nuna, iel bedaŭrinda.

Longa respondo:

Depende de la kunteksto vi povus uzi `amiko` kiel seksneŭtran vorton (kaj do teorie ankaŭ `koramiko`). Oni faris tion jam antaŭ longe. Jen citaĵo el *Fundamenta Krestomatio de la Lingvo Esperanto (1904)*:

> La malgrand’ruso pensis, ke la plej bona amiko de viro estas lia edzino,

Tamen, kutime, kaj ĉefe kiam oni precizigas `amiko` per artikolo aŭ aparteno, oni celas viron. `koramiko` estas ja preciza amiko kaj tial oni tre verŝajne komprenos ke temas pri viro.

Plurale `amikoj` reprenas sian seksneŭtran signifon, kvankam oni ankaŭ uzas `geamikoj` por substreki tion. Tial `koramikoj` povas esti ankaŭ seksneŭtra. Ekzemple: *"ili preferas laborejajn jarfinajn kunvenojn sen invititaj koramikoj, ĉar ĉiuj agas pli libere"*.

Mi povas atesti la kelkfojan familan uzon de `korpersono`. Se temas nur pri rapida demando, mi ankaŭ aŭdis `kora iu`, ekzemple: *"ĉu Eder havas koran iun?"*